# HTML tag or technique like <wbr> but for a line break?

Tags: html

I often find I wish to control how a sentence breaks/wraps, e.g.:

```
Hello there Mr Nemesis X, welcome to the interwebs!
```

If the viewport is narrow, I would like it to wrap after the comma, so the two logical lines are together:

i.e. **GOOD**: Only if the viewport is too narrow to show the whole screen

```
Hello there Mr Nemesis X,                |<----- viewport width
welcome to the interwebs!
```

**BAD**:

```
Hello there Mr Nemesis X, welcome to the |<----- viewport width
interwebs!
```

At the moment I place the two sentences in two `<span>`s, and use flex to ensure they wrap together, what a mission for something I often do. I learnt about `<wbr>`, which sounds like it could work if I replace all the spaces with say `&nbsp;`, but its not what it was defined for. Theres `<br>`, but that always breaks. So I am looking for something like a "line break", say `<lbr>` (doesnt exist), which if the line needs to wrap, it says hey, heres a good place to break the line.

Comment: CSS will not help you to do this, 
I think you have use JavaScript to pre-process your content according to viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe can use \n after the coma.

Comment: \n prints as a literal \n

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `<br>` html tag to break a line!

Comment: I mentioned that `<br>` in the question and specially said that it ALWAYS wraps, not only if required.

Answer (score -1):

The way your code is breaking right now is accurate to a break. The `<wbr>` is used to break a long word up hence why you would need to add that HTML entity to break up your lines.

For what I think you want, going for that specific design aesthetic, breaking at a comma, you would need to pre-process your strings before they get written, and as the view-port updates as to add breaks where you deem necessary.

Comment: Hence I asked something *like* `<wbr>` but for lines. I understand how `<wbr>` works.

Answer (score -2):

1. Inserting the line break tag after the comma.
2. Or you can use the /n after the comma.

Comment: I explained why line break tag is not applicable, and `/n` prints as a literal `/n`